# How to delete an object from a list inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, object

Let's say there are three lists, the third being a list containing the first two:

```
Friendly_List = list()
Enemy_List = list()
Battle_Space = list([Friendly_List, Enemy_List])
```

And a goblin class:

```
class Goblin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = "Goblin"
        self.HP = random.randint(15,20)
        self.Damage = random.randint(5,10)
```

I create an instance of the Goblin class:

```
x = Goblin()
```

Then put it into Friendly_List:

```
Friendly_List.append(x)
```

Now let's say the goblin dies heroically and must be removed from the battlefield. If I do Friendly_List.remove(x), the goblin is removed without issue.

If I do Battle_Space.remove(x), it says that x is not in the list - even though x is in one of the lists that is part of the Battle_Space list.

I guess what I'm trying to ask really is: what is the proper way to achieve the desired behavior of Battle_Space.remove(x)? To remove an instance that is a layer deep?

Comment: There are two possible interpretations to your question: do you want to remove `x` at a specific 'location' only or everywhere it may appear?

Comment: You must specify which list you are removing from: `Battle_Space[0].remove(x)`.

Comment: I want to remove x anywhere it may appear in the Battle_Space list.

Comment: @Kos implying that it is possible for a `Goblin` to end up in both the friendly and enemy lists?

Comment: Try using PEP-8 naming conventions for your variables and attribute. Names starting with a capital letter indicates a class, which will confuse other programmers if it's a variable or attribute. Name variables and attributes with all lowercase, and underscore if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple but maybe not-so-clean way is `Battle_Space[0].remove(x)`. You would have to ensure that the first list is the friendly list.

My suggestion for readability would be to consider putting `friendly_list` and `enemy_list` in a `BattleSpace` object so you can refer to them by name. You can also create a method in that object to remove a target from any child list:

```
class BattleSpace(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.friendly_list = []
        self.enemy_list = []

    def remove(self, target):
        if target in self.friendly_list:
            self.friendly_list.remove(target)
        if target in self.enemy_list:
            self.enemy_list.remove(target)


battle_space = BattleSpace()
battle_space.friendly_list.append(x)
battle_space.remove(x)  # can also do battle_space.friendly_list.remove(x)
```

**Edit:** Just read the OP's comment that the desire is to remove anywhere in the list. Modified code.

Comment: Definitely the better solution. Edit: it would also be worth it to add an attribute to the `Goblin` class to specify if it is friendly or not, so you know exactly which list to remove from.

Comment: How would I remove x from battle_list without knowing whether or not it is in friendly_list or enemy_list, but just knowing that it is in battle_list somewhere?

Comment: @Kos By checking both lists, as Karin has said, or by having an attribute on each `Goblin` instance. `self.type = 'friendly'` or `'self.type = 'enemy'`, then pass that variable to the `remove` function written by Karin. That's the cleanest way.

Comment: @Karin I would remove the comment in your last line of code. The point in functions like you have written, `remove()`, are typically a way to preform a task without allowing outsiders direct access to class variables. That's what `private` keywords in other languages are all about. It should be expected that if a function wants to manipulate lists owned by `BattleSpace` that it is only allowed to do so through `BattleSpace`'s provided methods.

Comment: Small note: Though list comprehension and filter will give you the correct thing, I preferred to not do that because they both create new lists, whereas remove will remove the item from the existing list. The memory you save by doing that is of course probably negligible for your use case though ;)

Comment: @jphollowed - I agree to an extent :) But this was a simple way to also allow only removing from one list (in case you only want to remove if it's friendly but not if it's an enemy, etc.). I also feel like the Pythonic approach is generally to aim for simplicity over security and trust the callers to be responsible - hence why it doesn't really have a simple equivalent to `private` as other languages do.

Comment: @Karin But it is also Pythonic to be explicit rather than implicit. I would rather explicitly provide functionality to remove from either list you choose, as opposed to implying that the caller can do it themselves. Just add a `which_list` argument to the `remove` function, that defaults to `None` or something, which signifies to search both lists.

Comment: How would you make an argument "default" like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the nested list, you can index from the parent list and call `remove`:

```
Battle_Space[0].remove(x)
```

To remove `x` from anywhere it appears, you can use a list comprehension:

```
Battle_Space = [[j for j in innerlist if j!=x] for innerlist in Battle_Space]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very concise answer Moses; you achieved my desired behavior in a single line. I will learn more about list comprehension so that I can incorporate into my code with knowing exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter those damm goblins out, for instance:

```
import random


class Goblin(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = "Goblin"
        self.HP = random.randint(15, 20)
        self.Damage = random.randint(5, 10)

x = Goblin()
Friendly_List = list()
Enemy_List = list()
Battle_Space = list([Friendly_List, Enemy_List])
Friendly_List.append(x)
Friendly_List.append(x)
Friendly_List.append(x)
Enemy_List.append(x)

print Battle_Space
for index, army in enumerate(Battle_Space):
    Battle_Space[index] = filter(lambda entity: entity != x, army)
print Battle_Space
```

The code will remove that damm duplicated goblin from all armies of your intergalactic battle.

I'm not a big fan of galactic battles, can goblins replicate themselves magically? :')

**EDIT**

If you wanted a more OOP approach, you'd transform the above code in something more like this:

```
import random


class Goblin(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = "Goblin"
        self.HP = random.randint(15, 20)
        self.Damage = random.randint(5, 10)


class Army(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.entities = []

    def remove(self, target):
        if target in self.entities:
            self.entities.remove(target)

    def filter(self, target):
        self.entities = filter(
            lambda entity: self.entities != entity, self.entities)


class BattleSpace(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.armies = []

    def remove(self, target):
        for index, army in enumerate(self.armies):
            army.remove(target)

    def filter(self, target):
        for index, army in enumerate(self.armies):
            army.filter(target)


x = Goblin()
battle_space = BattleSpace()
Friendly_List = Army()
Enemy_List = Army()
battle_space.armies = [Friendly_List, Enemy_List]
Enemy_List.entities.append(x)

print "Initial setup"
print Enemy_List.entities
print Friendly_List.entities

print "After removing"
battle_space.remove(x)
print Enemy_List.entities
print Friendly_List.entities
```

This way you could extend easily your BattleSpace to zillion of intergalactic armies from different planets

Comment: I think the OO approach suggested by Karin is a far better way to go. More organized, more versatile, and more consistent with the OP's code so far.

Comment: @jphollowed Well, I don't agree actually with you, IMHO the Karin's approach couples armies with the BattleSpace classes, that's not a good practice. I've edited my answer to make it more flexible

Comment: @Kos Out of curiosity, why do you think the other answers are better than this one?

Comment: They do what I need to do in less code and in a way that I can understand more (I'm still a beginner), that's all